# How to find de Mean and Variance of a defined distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I would like to find the Mean and Variance expressions for a Poisson-Lognormal Distribution

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{x!\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{x-1} e^{-\lambda} e^{\frac{(log(\lambda-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }\text{d}\lambda$$

I have been checking the `Expectation[]` command to find the expected value of predefined Mathematica `pdf`s but I do not know how to apply to this expression, and to find the $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

Comment: What didn't work with `Expectation`?  Please show what you tried.  Your LaTeX display seems to be in error.  $(\log(\lambda-\mu)^2$ should probably be $-(\log(\lambda)-\mu)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you will need to use numeric techniques.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_Integer?NonNegative,
  μ_?(NumericQ[#] && Element[#, Reals] &),
  σ_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)] := NIntegrate[
   E^-λ λ^(x - 
       1) E^(-(Log[λ] - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)),
   {λ, 0, ∞}]/(Sqrt[2 π] σ x!)

mean[μ_?(NumericQ[#] && Element[#, Reals] &),
  σ_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)] := mean[μ, σ] =
  NSum[x*f[x, μ, σ], {x, 0, ∞}, NSumTerms -> 50, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]

var[μ_?(NumericQ[#] && Element[#, Reals] &),
  σ_?(NumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)] := var[μ, σ] =
  Module[{m = mean[μ, σ]},
   NSum[(x - m)^2*f[x, μ, σ], {x, 0, ∞}, NSumTerms -> 50,
     WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]]

mean[0, 1]

(* 1.6487197 *)

var[0, 1]

(* 6.318 *)
```

Comment: @BobHanion Thank you. Both `mean[0,1]` and var[0,1]` gives me `ComplexInfinity` as a result.

Comment: I just pasted the code above into a notebook and executed it with the same result as shown above. I am running v12.0.0 on a Mac. Which version are you using?

Comment: @BobHanion I am running the 11.0.0 installed on a Mac too. That could be the issue.

Comment: On my Mac, code works with v11.3. The problem is present with v11.2. Perhaps you can upgrade to v11.3

Comment: @BonHanion I have downloades a 12.0 trial versioin and works fine. I suppose I should upgrade soon. I would ask you how I could get the \sigma such that `mean[2.32, \sigma]==23`?.

Comment: @BobHanion the problem I have found is that the algebraic expression of the mean[f()] if $e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$ and if I try to adjust the sigma to get a mean the result is wrong.

Comment: @BobHanion for example, running `Solve[Exp[2.32 + (s^2)/2] == 24 && s > 0, s]` I to get the sigma for a mean[]=24 results `s=1.31`. However, running `mean[2.32,1.31]= 22.8` which is different of 24.

Comment: If `Exp[\[Mu] + \[Sigma]^2/2]` is the actual mean and not an estimate, then use that in the definition of `mean`.